# Update wordpress Core Remotely

Tags: plugin-development

Im doing a project that needs to update the wordpress blog remotely like:

1. updating wordpress core
2. updating plugins
3. and updating themes

any help would be appreciated

thanks!

Comment: Remotely… how? Please post your code

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. You can install WP-CLI  - http://wp-cli.org/
   This will allow you to updates from the command line of your server.
2. Use revision control, Git, Mercurial, etc. That way you just pull in updates to your staging server or localhost and push updates to your sever.
3. Using a build script.
   You can have a build script located locally or on your server than will update wordpress for you via the command line or even cron job.
   There is a list of build scripts here: http://wpgear.org/ under "Command line fu".
4. Write your own bash/ruby/whatever script
5. Use a plugin, there are several that have this as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a plugin for that: infiniteWP. You might want to take a look at their code. ;)

Comment: Yeah i have seen it but im having a hard time understanding its code... :( im just new in wordpress development...

Comment: This is not an explanation or an answer. Please elaborate.